# Using Files.write to write a string into a file of specefic created folder

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to make a folder and then create/write  into a text file in such folder using Files.write. I'm trying the code below:

```
File d = new File("Zfolder");
d.mkdir();
String dpath = d.getAbsolutePath();
String textpath = dpath +  "\\test.txt";
Files.write(Paths.get(textpath ), "content".getBytes("utf_8"),StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

What I'm missing please ? I'm just moved from C# to Java, so, sorry for the poor coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `StandardOpenOption.CREATE` to create the file if it does not exist or use it if it does and add `StandardOpenOption.WRITE` to enable write access on it. Also your `Paths.get(gg)`, where is `gg` from?

**Note**: not `"content".getBytes("utf_8")`, it's `"content".getBytes("UTF-8")`

`Files.write(Paths.get(gg), "content".getBytes("utf_8"),StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);`

Comment: Shouldn't the  file.write will create the file when it not exist ? . Actually, I tried your code but still not working. Thank you

Comment: I have reviewed the code in terms of the "gg". Yes error

Comment: Also, `Files.write()` assumes `CREATE, WRITE` if you **do not** specify the mode

Comment: It works. Many thanks. the error was because of the utf-8

Comment: Sounds good. Yeah always pay attention to string names in Java

Comment: This error can be avoided by using `"content".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`…